# MySQL index query taking long time for specific column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49) tables that look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Document` (
    `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CompanyCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `B` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `C` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `DocumentCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `E` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `EpochSeconds` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `G` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `H` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `I` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `J` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `K` varchar(48) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    KEY `Idx1` (`CompanyCode`),
    KEY `Idx2` (`B`,`C`),
    KEY `Idx3` (`CompanyCode`,`DocumentCode`),
    KEY `Idx4` (`CompanyCode`,`B`,`C`),
    KEY `Idx5` (`H`),
    KEY `Idx6` (`CompanyCode`,`K`),
    KEY `Idx7` (`K`),
    KEY `Idx8` (`K`,`E`),
    KEY `NEWIDX` (`DocumentCode`,`EpochSeconds`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=397783215 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `Company` (
    `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `CompanyCode` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `CompanyName` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    `C` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    `D` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `E` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
    KEY `Idx1` (`CompanyCode`),
    KEY `Idx2` (`CompanyName`),
    KEY `Idx3` (`C`),
    KEY `Idx4` (`D`,`C`)
    KEY `Idx5` (`E`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9218804 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

*I've omitted most of the column definitions from `Company` because I don't want to complicate the question unnecessarily, but those missing columns are not involved in any `KEY` definitions.*

`Document` has ~12.5 million rows and `Company` has ~600,000 rows.
I've added the KEY `NEWIDX` to `Document` to facilitate the following query:

> SELECT  Document.*, Company.CompanyName FROM Document, Company where Document.DocumentCode = ? and Document.CompanyCode = Company.CompanyCode ORDER BY Document.EpochSeconds desc LIMIT 0, 30;

Execution Plan:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys                     | key         | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Company      | ALL  | Idx1                              | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                         | 593729 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Document     | ref  | Idx1,Idx4,Idx6,NEWIDX,Idx3        | Idx3        | 8       | db.Company.CompanyCode,const |      3 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------+--------+------------------------+
```

If the value for `Document.DocumentCode` above is anything other than `8`, then the query returns instantly (0.00 secs). If the value is `8`, then the query takes anywhere between 38 and 45 seconds. If I remove `Company` from the query e.g.

> SELECT * FROM Document where DocumentCode = 8 ORDER BY EpochSeconds desc LIMIT 0, 30;

Execution plan:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Documents | ref  | NEWIDX        | NEWIDX     | 4       | const | 3654177 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
```

...then the query returns instantly (0.00 secs).

- The range of possible values for `Document.DocumentCode` is 369, with a decent enough spread across those values.
- There are ~3.15 million rows in `Document` that have `DocumentCode` = 8.
- Also, consider that there are ~1.5 million rows in `Document` that have `DocumentCode` = 9, and that query returns instantly.

I've also run the `mysqlcheck` utility on the `Document` table and it doesn't report any problems.

Why might the query where the DocumentCode = 8 be taking so long when the `Company` join is used in the query, whereas any other value for `DocumentCode` returns so quickly?

---

Here's a comparison of the execution plans for DocumentCode = 8:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+-----------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys                     | key         | key_len | ref                          | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Company      | ALL  | Idx1                              | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                         | 593729 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Document     | ref  | Idx1,Idx4,Idx6,NEWIDX,Idx3        | Idx3        | 8       | db.Company.CompanyCode,const |      3 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+----------------------+--------+------------------------+
```

and DocumentCode = 9:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+----------------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys              | key    | key_len | ref                      | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+----------------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Document | ref  | Idx1,Idx4,Idx6,NEWIDX,Idx3 | NEWIDX | 4       | const                    | 1953090 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Company  | ref  | Idx1                       | Idx1   | 4       | db.Document.CompanyCode  |       1 |             |
+----+-------------+----------+------+----------------------------+--------+---------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

They're obviously different, but I don't understand them enough to interpret what's happening. Also, performing `ANALYZE TABLE Document` and `ANALYZE TABLE Company` both report `OK`.

Comment: Can you please add the execution plan of the queries ?

Comment: shouldn't joining condition come before filtering i.e. `...where Document.CompanyCode = Company.CompanyCode and Document.DocumentCode = ?` I think this optimize the query a bit

Comment: If you do an explain of the query using 8 and another with 9, are they the same? I suspect that MySQL might have reversed the join order between the 2 queries (possibly from out of date statistics - try doing _ANALYZE TABLE Document_ and _ANALYZE TABLE Company_ )

Comment: @Pramod reversing the clause order has no effect. I'll compare the explain between 8 and 9 now post back results...

Comment: I've added execution plan comparisons for DocumentCode 8 and 9. Please note that I originally posted incorrect total row counts in the bullet points. They're updated now.

Comment: @RTF - the analyze table rebuilds the statistics, so after doing that the indexes used by  the query (comparing 8 and 9) will hopefully change. But 3.5m records is 28% of the records on the documents table which is borderline as to whether MySQL will chose to use an index. While I am not keen on their use you could try using an index hint, or possibly just use a STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the order the tables are joined

Comment: @Kickstart query for 8 after analyzing the tables still runs at 35-40 secs. Could you post an answer, maybe, with an example query of what you're proposing with an index hint or STRAIGHT_JOIN?

Comment: In any case you have problematic design that should be changed if possible. `Document` should be connected to `Company` by its primary key `Company.Id` and not by `Company.Code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a STRAIGHT_JOIN to force the order that MySQL does the join in

```
SELECT Document.*, 
Company.CompanyName 
FROM Document
STRAIGHT_JOIN Company 
ON Document.CompanyCode = Company.CompanyCode
WHERE Document.DocumentCode = ? 
ORDER BY Document.EpochSeconds DESC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: This results in the 8 query returning instantly. I understand the disadvantage, in that this is limiting MySQL's ability to choose what it thinks is the most efficient way to perform the query (incorrectly in this case), but given that my tables will (slowly) grow over time, should I be concerned about anything?

Comment: Probably not in this case. More worrying is specifying a particular index to use, just in case someone deletes or renames that index in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour lies in the way mysql optimizes your query - or at least tries to. You see that in the explained queries. Mysql changes the table it uses as a basis for the query. With documentCode = 8 it's based on company, with documentCode=9 it's based on document. Mysql thinks, that for documentCode=8 it will be faster, if it's not using the index but instead using the other table as basis. Why exactly I do not know.

I would adivse you to use an explizit join, to tell mysql wich tables to use in wich order:

```
SELECT Document.*, Company.CompanyName 
FROM Document 
JOIN Company ON Document.CompanyCode = Company.CompanyCode 
WHERE Document.DocumentCode = ?
ORDER BY Document.EpochSeconds desc LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Mysql even supports telling it, what index it should use:

```
SELECT Document.*, Company.CompanyName 
FROM Document 
JOIN Company USE INDEX Idx1 ON Document.CompanyCode = Company.CompanyCode 
WHERE Document.DocumentCode = ?
ORDER BY Document.EpochSeconds desc LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Instead of USE INDEX you can also try FORCE INDEX. That's stronger. But I guess it will by default use Idx1.

But be advised that your new index NEWIDX will not be used for this query, because it needs to join first and filter the result set - which has no index. So this ORDER BY on the results is a very expensive operation.

Comment: Note that the order you put the explicit joins like that will not force the order that MySQL does the joins in